# Where is 2 table listing error (Help)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM
                        (SELECT paymentTop, salesTop, 
                            t1.id, t1.sno, t1.fadi, t1.sal_date, 
                            t2.pno, t2.pay_date 
                        FROM
                            (
                            SELECT id,sno,fadi,sal_date,
                                SUM(sales) AS salesTop 
                            FROM table1 
                            WHERE id='11'
                                GROUP BY sno
                            ) AS t1
                         LEFT JOIN
                            (
                            SELECT id, pno, fadi, pay_date
                                SUM(payment) AS paymentTop
                            FROM table2 
                            WHERE id='11'
                                GROUP BY pno
                            ) AS t2
                            ON t1.id = t2.id 
                         ) AS t3
                              GROUP BY sno, pno
                             ORDER BY sal_date, pay_date
```

```
t1 (table 1)                                    t2 (table 2)
+-------------------------------------+         +---------------------------------------+
| id | sal_date   |   no    |  sales  |         | id  |  pay_date  |  no    |   payment |
+-------------------------------------+         +---------------------------------------+
| 11 | 20/02/2018 | 006089  |   160.80|         | 11  | 15/03/2018 |    01815  |  93.85 |
+-------------------------------------+         +---------------------------------------+
| 11 | 13/03/2018 | 008834  |   219.60|         | 11  | 25/03/2018 |    07734  |  350,70|
+-------------------------------------+         +---------------------------------------+
| 11 | 13/03/2018 | 008834  |   143.81|     
+-------------------------------------+
| 11 | 21/03/2018 | 010257  |    51.00|     
+-------------------------------------+
| 11 | 21/03/2018 | 010257  |   553.21|     
+-------------------------------------+
the output I want
+------------------------------------------------+
| id |    date   |   no     |  sales  |  payment |
+------------------------------------------------+
| id |20/02/2018 | 006089   |   160.80|          |
+------------------------------------------------+
| id |13/03/2018 | 008834   |   363.41|          |
+------------------------------------------------+
| id |15/03/2018 | 01815    |         |   93.85  |
+------------------------------------------------+
| id |21/03/2018 | 010257   |   604.21|          |
+------------------------------------------------+
| id |25/03/2018 | 07734    |         |  350,70  |
+------------------------------------------------+
query output
+----------------------------------------+
|    date   |   no  |  sales  |  payment |
+----------------------------------------+
|20/02/2018 |006089 |   160.80|    93.85 |
+----------------------------------------+
|20/02/2018 |07734  |   160.80|   350,70 |
+----------------------------------------+
|13/03/2018 |008834 |   219.60|    93.85 |
+----------------------------------------+
|15/03/2018 |07734  |   219.60|   350,70 |
+----------------------------------------+
|21/03/2018 |010257 |   553.21|    93.85 |
+----------------------------------------+
|25/03/2018 |07734  |   553.21|   350,70 |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please add some verbal description of your task.

Answer (score 0):

try left join between two tables

```
select t1.id ,t1.sal_date,t1.no,t1.sales,t2.payment
left join t2
on t1.id=t2.id
and t1.no=t2.no
```

Comment: Dear @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin.
thank you. do you examine the table structure